# Infimum and supremum of the set of all numbers whose square is greater than 2

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Suppose, $S= \{ x \in \mathbb R\mid x^2 > 2\}$. Then $\sup S = +\infty$. What is 
$\inf S$?

I'm guessing that $\inf S \in (-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2)$. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

No. What if $x = -2?\quad -4? \quad -333337899999 ?$

Can you see that $\inf S = -\infty$

The interval you suggest, actually the interval $[-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2]$ is excluded from $S$, so that $S = \mathbb R \setminus [-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2]$.

Comment: im sorry im abit slow. but x=-4 would give x^2 =16 so it isnt inf s? ???

Comment: Right, and $16 \gt 2$, correct? The elements of $S$ here are the $x$'s that makes $x^2 >2$.  The members of $S$ are not the values $x^2$.  Remember, $S$ consists of all real numbers $x$ for which $x^2 >2$ is true.  $\;x = -4\,$ is one such $\,x\in S\,$ because $\,x^2 = (-4)^2 =16 > 2$.

Comment: Oh i get it now since x<-2 or x>2 because x^2>2. so sup S = plus infinity and inf would be the lowest point of x<-2 which is minus infinity! thank you so much! i really appreciate your help~!!

Comment: You are very welcome, faith!